# Where should these AS3 variables go?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, variables, actionscript, scope

I am trying to build the foundations for a platformer game in Actionscript 3. I'm still fairly novice at AS3, but I'm hoping this will help build my knowledge.

Anyway,

I understand that I can create Actionscript files that are associated with something such as a Sprite or a MovieClip by extending the Sprite/Movieclip class. I also know about Actionscript files that work as the 'Document class'.

Each level in my game will have different properties that vary such as gravity. Where should I store these variables? Obviously not in the player... Not sure if they're supposed to go in the timeline or the document class, or if they have a separate AS file of their own. I've been told that having global variables is generally bad, so I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can make levels as separate files that are even not Actionscript, but XML or JSON, since your levels are basically data structures with different starting values. And you can make a Level class that can take such a file, parse it and initialize an in-game level structure based on what's read. Yes, such data should not go to timeline, because should you need to change one piece of that data, it could implicitly affect other game processes. Also, one simple right click can ruin such a game :) I myself use JSON files as my level data holders, and I parse them at the initialization time, you can do like this or say when your level is being loaded.

In short, if something is different by initial data, but common in methods, it should reside separately from main code, or entire code, and be included as data.

Answer (score 1):

I think this similar question and answers will help you somewhat:

[As3 OOP game structure (class architecture)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486032/as3-oop-game-structure-class-architecture)

Basically, "What you want to do is to separate what changes in your game from the game itself". So definitely do not include the code in the timeline.